# Toggle select all checkboxes - not disabled

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a script which toggle selects all checkboxes in a table/form - but I need to amend to only toggle/check those which are NOT disabled. Kind assistance would be hugely appreciated.

```
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('chkInvID');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('input[name="chkInvID"]:not(:disabled)')`

Comment: Linked post uses jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simple condition :

```
function toggle(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('chkInvID');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    if(!checkboxes[i].disabled){
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect @abvlle, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to target all the *enabled* inputs which allows any valid [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). You can also use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through the elements which is more cleaner:

```js
function toggle(source) {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="chkInvID"]:enabled');
  [].slice.call(checkboxes).forEach(function(chk){
    chk.checked = source.checked;
  });
}

document.querySelector('input[name="source"]').addEventListener('change', function(){toggle(this)});
```

```html
<input name="source" type="checkbox"/>source<br>
<input name="chkInvID" type="checkbox" />
<input name="chkInvID" type="checkbox" disabled/>
<input name="chkInvID" type="checkbox" />
```